# Rails - Trying to learn cancan, but where does @user object come from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I just created a rails app with the rails composer with devise/cancan/rolify and i'm looking at some of the code that it generated and I'm not sure where `@user` comes from in this snippet:

/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end

end
```

/models/ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    end
end
```

Where does the `@user` variable get set? I would have expected to see `current_user` there.

**EDIT**

I feel like I must not be explaining myself clearly so lets try this.

1) This works

```
def index
    authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
end
```

2) This works

```
def index
    authorize! :index, current_user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
end
```

3) This does NOT work

```
def index
    authorize! :index, @my_user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
end
```

My question is why does 1) work, but 3) does not?

Comment: Generally that would be `current_user` - is there anything weird in the `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` that might be setting `@user`?

Comment: I added application_controller to my question. The weirdest thing is that it somehow works too. When i login as a user without the admin role, i get the message "not authorized as an administrator", but when i login as an admin i don't get that message

Comment: devise will define a `@current_user` instance variable as well, but not a `@user` one. see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L58

Comment: @Catfish Are you sure that 3) doesn't work? I mean: did you try that very code and it didn't work in both admin and non admin modes?

Comment: Please, read my updated answer. I fear you have got a little misunderstanding on how ability checking works.

Comment: Just a tip but I spent an hour answering your question. The least you could do is upvote it or comment on it. If you can't be bothered to do either then it only discourages people from bothering to respond.

Comment: @PeterNixey Sorry i haven't made it back to this project yet this week. Hoping to do so soon.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the [cancan README](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan#getting-started):

> CanCan expects a current_user method to exist in the controller.

So cancan *does* depend on devise's `current_user` in authorization, it checks if the `current_user` is `authorize!`d to do the `:action`, and doesn't (as you might have guessed) check if the second parameter (which is in this case `@user`) is authorized to do that action.

#### Then what is the second parameter of authorize! ?

The second parameter of `authorize!` is actually the object on which the action (first parameter) is to be checked. In other words (and assuming the case in your code):

**cancan will check if the `current_user` has the permissions to `:index` the `@user`**

Explaining the case in your comment:

> The weirdest thing is that it somehow works too. When i login as a user without the admin role, i get the message "not authorized as an administrator", but when i login as an admin i don't get that message

Since you have not given any permissions to non-`:admin` users in your `/models/ability.rb`, then  they will not be able to perform any action, no matter what action it is and what object(s) it's performed on, even if on a `nil`! - which seems to be your case. On the other hand, you have granted users with the `:admin` role all (`:manage`) permissions on all (`:all`) objects in your /models/ability.rb, so they're able to do any action on any object no matter what it is, even a `nil`!

Comment: Dude that was my bad - I totally hit the wrong arrow.  I made an edit so I could change my vote.  Great answer.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I shouldn't be allowed to use SO on my iPhone when the Ballmer Curve is involved. :)

Comment: I feel like this answer doesn't relate to my question at all (unless i missed the point). My question is `Where does the @user variable get set?`

Comment: @Catfish It doesn't. It's passed to `authorize!` as `nil`. What `authorize!` really uses in authorization is not `@user`, but rather `current_user` as mentioned in the readme linked in the answer.

Comment: @Catfish - it actually does.  My answer was wrong (thus why I deleted it).  Tamer is right - `@user` doesn't get set, but in this case, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting a `@user` variable instantiated here. You are simply working with a method that get a `user` local variable passed to.

What this `user` variable contains really depends on the `cancan` gem. It will work reading the commonly used `current_user` helper method so that `cancan` works fine with `devise` and other similar gems.

In fact, when no user is logged in, you force

```
user ||= User.new
```

to be able to handle guests users. But this is all matter of method-local variables.

### For a more detailed insight

#### Defining abilities

Probably you are misunderstanding how the `authorize!` and `can?` methods work.

So, `cancan` will try to verify if `current_user` is capable of doing something. What the current logged in user (`current_user`) is able to do has to be defined in the `ability.rb` file.

Abilities have this form (easiest case):

```
_user_ can _action_ on _model_or_instance_
```

When you wright this on the `Ability` class:

```
def initialize(user)
  can :read, Document
end
```

you are really saying that the current logged in user can read all instances of the `Document` model:

```
user can :read Document #pseudo-code
```

That `user` that will be passed to the `initialize` method will always be `current_user` or `nil`.

#### Checking/authorizing abilities

In your controllers you want to check for abilities. Ok. So you go with:

```
authorize! :index, @user
```

And this will be converted in something like

```
verify if current_user can :index @user #pseudo-code
```

When you change it to:

```
authorize! :index, current_user
```

It's the equivalent of

```
verify if current_user can :index current_user #pseudo-code
```

#### What you want to do

You are trying to authorize `current_user` to do what? `:index` on what controller/model?

Eg. I want to be able to manager users only if the current logged in user is an administrator

The best way to do this is, keeping your `Ability` definitions:

```
authorize! :index, User
```

so that you are authorizing the current_user to operate on the whole `User` models.

#### Warning

You should not pass to the `authorize!` and `can?` methods the user you want to check the abilites for. That user will always be `current_user`. Eg. you cannot get an instance of `User` and check if that instance has this or that ability. `cancan` will alway use as "main character" the logged in user (or nil, if there is none).

#### Why 3) is not working

3) will work as intended (and as 1) and 2)) if and only if you logged in to the application and the current user is an administrator. So, it will not work if:

1. You are not logged in, *and*
2. You are not an admin

In all other cases (you logged in as an admin) it will work. Please, check this first.

#### Bonus

If you're an administrator (given your `Ability` definition) this will always be true:

```
can? :any_action_of_your_choice, nil
```

since you stated that admins

```
can :manage, :all
```

From your examples, no matter what you set after `authorize! :index,`, it will always authorize if you logged in as an admin (eg. `current_user.has_role? admin`).

Answer (score 1):

Ahh man - I should be working not answering questions on SO however...

TLDR; The `@user` variable is NOT being set and that's why your code is odd.

### You're conflating the resource with the person accessing it

Let me take your first use case and explain what's happening:

```
# Case 1
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

### You already have real (but confusing) bug

At this stage you actually have a bug. You're getting confused between the person who's accessing the resource, `current_user` and the resource you're giving them access which is `@user`. I am Peter (`current_user`) but I might be trying to access John's (`@user`) user page. John is the resource that I am requesting access to.

In your code **you've not actually loaded the resource you're wanting to grant access to**. Let me break down step by step what's going on.

*I'm going to use the show action because it's easier to see what's going on but the same things applies to `index` too*

Let's assume I, Peter am trying to access your (Catfish's) page:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # first let's get explicit about who's accessing the page
    @current_user = current_user 

    # now we need to load up the page I'm trying to access
    @user = User.find params[:id]

    # can I, Peter, access the :show action of this profile?
    authorize! :show, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'

    # rest of your controller...
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

This loads up me, `current_user` and then loads up you, `@user` and then asks whether I have permission to access your `:show` action.

### What was happening in your cases

The fact that you're using the index action is doubly confusing as there isn't any resource to load there. I'm therefore going to explain what's going on using the show action:

```
# case 1
# this requests access FOR current_user TO @user
# I have no idea what the value of @user is (probably nil)
def show
  authorize! :show, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
  @users = User.all
end

# case 2
# this requests access FOR current_user TO current_user
def show
  # this is not what you want
  authorize! :show, current_user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
  @users = User.all
end

# case 3)
# This requests access FOR current_user TO @my_user
# I have no idea what the value of @my_user is (probably nil)
def show
  authorize! :show, @my_user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
  @users = User.all
end
```

### You need to load the resource first and pass that resource to the ability file

Your current user is loaded for you by the `authenticate_user!` method. However you need to make sure that the resource you're trying to access is also loaded. In the case of the `:show` action this would happen like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # load the resource you want to protect access to
    @user = params[:id]

    # use cancan to see whether anyone can access it
    authorize! :show, @user
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

However depending on whether this is the last level in nesting the id for the resource may be `id` or `user_id`. On the `:index` action there won't be either of these params at all. All this is a pain however cancan handles this nicely for you using `load_resource`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # CanCan figures out that the resource is a User and then gets it using the params
    load_resource 
    # @user is now set. 
    # If the URL is http://yoursite.com/users/5, then @user.id == 5

    authorize! :show, @user
    @users = @user # not actually necessary since load_resource has already done this
  end
end
```

Now cancan makes it even easier by combining the load and authorize steps

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # figures out what you want to load and authorizes it (sweet)
    load_and_authorize_resource
    # @user will now be equal to User.find(params[id])
    # no need to load @user - it's already been done
  end
end
```

Finally, you can pull these out into a before_filter so you don't have to write them at all

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter load_and_authorize_resource :user
  def show
    # in a pure CRUD app you literally won't need any code in your show action
  end
end
```

### Ways to make this all easier to understand

1. Don't use the users resource to learn cancan
   Use Pages, Articles or anything else. It will help make it clear to you which part is the resource, `@page`, and which part is the current user `@current_user`
2. Don't learn on the index action
   The index action doesn't actually load a particular resource since there isn't one to load. This again makes things more difficult to understand. See what's happening on `:show` or `:edit` and then move to the actions which don't take a resource (`:new`, `:index`, `:create`)